# How to set iteration count value to a filed in java

Tags: java, count, iteration

I have a list which iterate via a for-each loop. So what i want is once value set into `customerAttemptTemp.setIsActive("N")   customerAttemptTemp.setAttemptCount();` seted value should be 1.

**finally customerAttemptList  list`s size 5 attempt count need to be 5.**

this is the code segment.

```
 List<CustomerAttempt> customerAttemptList = customerAttemptService.findCustomerAttempts(customerAttemptWrong, _serviceContext);
      for (CustomerAttempt customerAttemptTemp : customerAttemptList) {
                    customerAttemptTemp.setIsActive("N");
                     customerAttemptTemp.setIsActive( // **Where the count need to be updated**);
                    customerAttemptService.update(customerAttemptTemp, _serviceContext);
      }
```

Comment: I attempted to answer your question, but sorry, I virtually had dificulties in getting what your objective is.

Comment: @L.Anush it's better to store count in session if not then use the database to count the attempt. its for login or other purpouse

Comment: forget that sir, i just said if i can do the same using for loop also ok.

Comment: yeah i want to store the count to the database for a capthcha removal process.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need a regular for loop. `for (int i = 0; i < calist.size(); i++) { ... calist.get(i).setIsActive(i + 1); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by introducing a `count` variable outside of the loop, then just increase it after every iteration

```
int count = 1;
for(CustomerAttempt customerAttemptTemp : customerAttemptList) {
    customerAttemptTemp.setIsActive("N");
    customerAttemptTemp.setIsActive(count++);
    customerAttemptService.update(customerAttemptTemp, _serviceContext);
}
```

Comment: Sir here . when the first iteration goes setIsActive count value becomes 2 ryt? hence declared value 1.

Comment: @L.Anush `count++` gets the value and then increases it afterwards, so the first attempt will have a count of `1` the fifth attempt a count of `5`

Comment: @L.Anush you can start with 0 as well. Depends on your requirement. Just check the logic provided by Lino . Values you can change.. Also according to current logic. the value stored inside the setIsActive will be up to 5. however the value of count will be 6. I guess there is no issue. this logic should work.

Comment: I think lino is correct. what i want 1 attempt count to 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (int count = 0 ; count < customerAttemptList.size(); count++) {
    customerAttemptList.get(count).setIsActive("N");
    customerAttemptList.get(count).setIsActive(count + 1);
    customerAttemptService.update(customerAttemptList.get(count), _serviceContext);
}
```